# How can I count pulse inputs with some interval time?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I'm develop a pulse counter(coin counter) in raspberry pi with windows 10 iot core, and i need to count pulses that have a interval time of 25 miliseconds like this:

0,05€ - 1 pulse
0,10€ - 2 pulses
0,20€ - 4 pulses
0,50€ - 10 pulses
1€ - 20 pulses
2€ - 40 pulses

like this image: [pulses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1erO.png)

I need to print the number of pulses(to have the value inserted) when the interval time is diferent of 25 miliseconds.

I have this code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitGPIO();
    }

    private void InitGPIO()
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        if (gpio == null)
        {
            GpioStatus.Text = "There is no GPIO controller on this device.";
        }

        coinPin = gpio.OpenPin(coin_Pin);

        if (coinPin.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp))
        {
            coinPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
        } else
        {
            coinPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
        }

        coinPin.DebounceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25);

        coinPin.ValueChanged += coinPin_ValueChanged;

        GpioStatus.Text = "GPIO pins initialized correctly.";
    }

    private void coinPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
        {
            counter++;
        }

        var task = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
            {
                //counter++;
                var time = PulseIn(coinPin, e.Edge);
                value = (counter * 5);
                value100 = value / 100;
                //money.Text = "Eur: " + (decimal)value100 + " €";

                if (time != 25)
                {
                    money.Text = "Eur: " + (decimal)value100 + " €";
                    GpioStatus.Text = "" + time;
                } else
                {
                    GpioStatus.IsEnabled = false;
                }
                //GpioStatus.Text = "" + time + "";
            } else
            {
                ///GpioStatus.Text = "" + coinPin.DebounceTimeout;
            }


        });
    }

    private double PulseIn(GpioPin pin, GpioPinEdge edge)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        while (edge.Equals(GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge))
        {
            //sw.Start();
        }

        sw.Start();

        if (!edge.Equals(GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge))
        {
            //sw.Stop();
        }

        sw.Stop();

        return sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    }


    private const int coin_Pin = 24;
    private int counter = 0;
    private double value = 0;
    private double value100 = 0;
    private GpioPin coinPin;
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From your code,

```
    sw.Start();

    if (!edge.Equals(GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge))
    {
        //sw.Stop();
    }

    sw.Stop();
```

it actually measures the execute time of the `if` statement that between `sw.Start()` and `sw.Stop()`. This does not make sense. Record the `watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` when the falling edge arrived and restart the stopwatch to measure the pulse interval time. To do this, I add the following two code lines under `counter++`, remove `var time = PulseIn(coinPin, e.Edge)` and use `timeinterval` in `GpioStatus.Text = "" + timeinterval` instead.

```
            timeinterval = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            watch.Restart();
```

The following is complete code piece:

```
    private Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    private void coinPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double timeinterval = 0;
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
        {
            counter++;
            timeinterval = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            watch.Restart();
        }

        var task = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
            {
                //var time = PulseIn(coinPin, e.Edge);
                value = (counter * 5);
                value100 = value / 100;

                if (timeinterval != 25)
                {
                    money.Text = "Eur: " + (decimal)value100 + " €";
                    GpioStatus.Text = "" + timeinterval;
                }
                //...
            }
        });
    }
```

You can try above code piece to see if it meets your accuracy requirement.

Note: It is not suitable to measure hardware pulse interval in software level because the software jitter is always unpredictable.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example input of 2 coins (0,2€ and 0,05€) the result should be 0,20€ and 0,25€, and now show "0,05 0,1 0,15 0,20 0,25"... i'm only need to show the total value.

Comment: How do you input of 0,2€? Doesn't it have four pulses?